# How to recognize touch on the home screen

Tags: android, touch

I am very new to android. I just want to know how can i recognize the touch on the screen of android phone.

Till now what i did, created an application and on that application view i am able to recognize the touch.

Please refer screen shot to know that where i am able to recognize touch.

[image]

Please refer screen shot where i am not able to recognize touch.

[image]

Please give me some suggestion how to recognize touch on main screen of android phone.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the `onTouchListener`.

Here is an example code, you can use any view to trigger this method:

```
    yourView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){ //When finger is lifted off the screen

                // Do what you want, for example, raise a Toast:
Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this, "Screen has been touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Read more [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Hope this has helped!

Comment: How to recognize touch on home screen that what i want.

Comment: AFAIK, You cannot intercept touches on Home Screen - unless you create a Launcher App - and then you can do whatever you want.
The code example I provided can recognize touches on a View **in your app**

Comment: Could you let me know that how to create a launcher app.

Comment: 1) If this is what you want, you should rephrase your question.
2) Writing a HomeScreen App is not simple, start looking at these sites:
[1](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/how-to-write-custom-launcher-app-in-android/)
[2](http://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_write_custom_launcher_app_in_Android)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that outside your own app. Home screen is like another app(System) for your app. Detecting actions in another app is a kind of intrusion and android won't allow that.

If you create your own launcher, you can. But cannot detect touches with the system default launcher.